GrammY telegram bot to do multiple selection and edit the Inline Keyboard button
I wanted to do the multiple selections for the grammY telegram bot but it seems not working
async function generatePayslipSelection(conversation: MyConversation, ctx: MyContext) {
    try {
        await ctx.reply(`Payslip Type`, {
            reply_markup: buildPayslipSelection()
        });
        
        const is_edit_message = await bot.api.editMessageReplyMarkup(ctx.update.message.chat.id, ctx.update.message.message_id);
        console.log(is_edit_message);

        // await ctx.editMessageReplyMarkup()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

I need to add in emoji while pressing button and remove an emoji while pressing button twice
export function buildPayslipSelection() {
    let inline_keyboard = new InlineKeyboard();
    let payslip = 0;
    for (const key in PayslipType) {
        const value = PayslipType[key];
        payslip++;

        inline_keyboard.text(value, value);

        // Move to next row when current row is filled up by 2 features
        if (payslip % 2 == 0) {
            inline_keyboard.row();
        }
    }
    return inline_keyboard;
}

the final data will stores in an array
